# How to export Xcore to Ecore?

Tags: eclipse-emf, ecore, mdd, xcore

Defining metamodels with Xcore is a lot easier than with EMF and Ecore. The problem is that I need the metamodels as Ecore files. Is it possible to export Xcore model to Ecore model? I don't see any export options in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore#Converting_an_Xcore_Model_to_a_GenModel) describes how to export an Xcore model to a GenModel.
It looks like the same can be done with the Ecore Model. Especially because the author mentions:

> [...] Xcore resource does physically contain a GenModel and an Ecore model [...]

Comment: I saw that, but how to generate the ecore file?

Comment: I just followed the steps from the wiki. The importer will actually create the Ecore next to the GenModel, without any additional steps.
I tested this using Xcore SDK 1.0.2 and Eclipse 4.2.2.

Comment: thanks very much! I didn't finished the tutorial because i thought that it would generate only the genmodel.