# How to create an Xcore resource from an Ecore model?

Tags: modeling, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, xcore

I have an existing Ecore model that I would like to modify. For modifying I would like to use Xcore. An [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975879/1466267) says, that it is possible to import classes from an Ecore model to an Xcore resource. However since I would like to change existing classes, this doesn't work for me.

Reading the [eclipsepedia entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore) for Xcore nor searching the web didn't bring anything useful.

So how can I create an Xcore resource from an Ecore model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [eclipse forum entry](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1160861/) led me to the correct path:

First you need to create a genmodel for the ecore model. This is done via `New` -> `Other` -> `EMF Generator Model` and following the steps in the wizard. After that go to the context menu of the genmodel and select `Export Model...` -> `Xcore` and follow the steps in the wizard.

EDIT:
In the meanwhile I also found the mentioning of this in the Eclipsepedia article: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore#Converting_a_GenModel_to_an_Xcore_Model